# EJBAccessException when accessing a Security Domain

Tags: java, security, ejb, jboss7.x, rbac

I'm trying to get to run a simple RBAC example with EJBs but when the client calls a method from a class that has a SecurityDomain I get: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User.

Here's my setup:

- Server Project

  - EJB 3.1
  - JBoss AS 7.1
  - Picketbox (the 3 jar files that come with the download)

The client is a simple java project

My class in the server project that i would like to secure later  looks like the following:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBean implements SomeRemote, SomeLocal {
  @Override 
  public void unsecuredMethod(Object obj) {     
    //do something
  }
}
```

In jboss-ejb3.xml from META-INF I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:s="urn:security"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
              version="3.1"
              impl-version="2.0">
<assembly-descriptor>
  <s:security>
    <ejb-name>SomeBean</ejb-name>
    <s:security-domain>SomeDomain</s:security-domain>
  </s:security>
</assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

I use this file because I'm not able to import the org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain annotation. (Maybe I have wrong dependencies?)

In standalone-full.xml from jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration I have:

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
  <security-domains>
  ...
    <security-domain name="SomeDomain" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
          <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/DefaultDS"/>
          <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM Customer WHERE username=?"/>
          <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT rolename, 'Roles' FROM Role WHERE username=?"/>
          <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
      </authentication>
    </security-domain>
  </security-domains>
</subsystem>
...
```

The exception occurs no matter if i attempt to authenticate within the client with

```
SecurityClient secClient =     
SecurityClientFactory.getSecurityClient();          
secClient.setSimple("username1", "password1");
secClient.login();
```

or just go with the guest role that the client should recieve if i don't authenticate him (because of: name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"). Another thing is that the LoginException from the SecurityClient does not seem to be thrown even if i provide false credentials. After this i make a normal lookup for the SomeBean class and cast it to SomeRemote. When calling unsecuredMethod(..) the exception occurs. I tried it with both, giving the guest-user a role in the Role table and without.

Within the client project I didn't do anything rbac or ejb related except using the SecurityClient and the lookup, I hope this is correct.

Maybe there is some good tutorial that explains everything. I may have the problem because my solution is based on a Jboss AS 6 tutorial.

**Edit:** After searching the internet for this exception for hours I found a hint in a book that says that if jboss cannot find the database tables used for authentication you will always get the message: "Invalid User". So probably i have a problem with my data source configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an EJB being accessed remotely you will also need to update the security realm (ApplicationRealm) associated with the Remoting connector to use a jaas reference to your security domain so that the user can be authenticated on the inbound connection.